# How do I import/use rfft in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently, tensorflow added support for rfft and irfft functions. See [this github-issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/386), it was added [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2d23960e29c3efb1b30c5cb6f8f3368635b97f29/tensorflow/python/ops/spectral_ops.py) in the code. Now I would like to use these functions in my models. I am working in a docker environment, so I ran the nightly image (since this was added very recently). The one I used was: 'tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-devel-gpu'.
I checked and the file with the rfft ops was indeed in this image, at:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/spectral_ops.py
```

Then I tried importing these functions, something like this should work in my mind:

```
>>> from tensorflow import rfft
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name rfft
```

However, strangely enough, this does work without error:

```
>>> from tensorflow import fft
```

Also when I call:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dir(tf)
```

Then in the long list it shows the fft and ifft functions, but not the rfft and irfft functions. Im assuming I don't have the wrong version, since I can check the code I want is on the image. Also, I don't think this is an installation issue, since I am using a clean docker environment directly from the people at tensorflow.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, the solution is to use:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.spectral_ops import rfft
```